# Is there any server configuration or anything that make __DIR__ failed

Tags: php

I have develop a framework where most of its path depend on `__DIR__`. Is there any server configuration or anything that would make `__DIR__` unreliable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not having PHP 5.3 would be a deal breaker. You could use `dirname(__FILE__)` if you don't want to require 5.3.

Other than that, no, it should always be available.